# How to make an Image button circular and inside the circle,an image will be shown and a border will be there around the image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

I have been looking SO how to make an Image button circular and inside the circle, an image will be shown. But I could not find any helpful sources. I have only 24 hours and my client will check it.

My aim is to create Image Button(black colored circle, see the picture below and an image can be displayed inside it). See image below:

[image]

**Here is my XML part...the ImageButton is between two comment lines**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="sudhirpradhan.example.com.clientpptapp.mainIconFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4.5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

<!--here is my imageButton need to be look like a circle and within that circle ,a picture will be shown .............. -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:src="@drawable/frontbutton" />
<!-- ..........................................................-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**here is @drawable/roundbutton xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#50d050"
        android:endColor="#008000"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke android:width="5px"
        android:color="#000000"/>

</shape>
```

How can I implement that..any suggestion and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW EDITION**

As per your comments I got a better idea of what you needed so I'll provide here (re-edited) the solution I have for you.

First I extended an ImageView like this:

```
public class CircleImageView extends AppCompatImageView {


    private int borderColor;
    private float borderWidth;



    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        if(b == null || b.isRecycled())
            return;
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        int imgRadius = w - 2 * (int)this.borderWidth;

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(this.borderColor);
         canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth() / 2,
                this.getHeight() / 2,
                this.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, imgRadius);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, this.borderWidth, this.borderWidth, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                    false);
        else
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(
                finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }


    private void parseAttributes(AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView);

        this.borderColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, 0xffffff); // default color white
        this.borderWidth = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, 1.0f);
    }

}
```

Then we need to set some styleable attributes for borderColor and borderWidth, place it in res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
        <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="border_width" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then you can just include it in your layout - it will be like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="10"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="4.5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <!--here is my imageButton need to be look like a circle and within that circle ,a picture will be shown .............. -->

        <com.mucodes.roundbuttonexample.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:border_color="#ffff0000"
            app:border_width="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/random"/>

        <!-- ..........................................................-->



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can then use the method setOnClickListener to make the CircleImageView act like a button when clicked.

Here is a video of the result: [example of using](https://youtu.be/A54Q6ZbQFBc)

Hope now this is what you need.

Comment: Any source code link to implement a square/rectangular image inside image button ..??

Comment: I've edited my post. Take a look if it is the result that you need.

Comment: this image is just placed over the button ..if I use padding= 5px then the Image hides the circle and come out of circle ..what I need is Image should not come out of the circle ..it should be inside the circle always like in case of no padding.... thank you

Comment: I edited my post with a solution for what you need, please check it out.

Comment: I saw the video, yes that's what I wanted to implement for my project...you made a video for this!!! man thanks a ton.

Comment: You're welcome! Video was the best way I've found to show how it works.
Remember to add **xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** in your layout root element so you can use the custom attributes **app:border_color** and **app:border_width**

Comment: I think this **int imgRadius = w - 2 * (int)this.borderWidth;** will be better change to **_int imgRadius = w - (int)this.borderWidth;_**, seems like the way it is now is making border width twice its defined size.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can not comment due to a reputation.

Try to take a look at [fancy buttons library](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons).
Here you can set a radius to your button, background color, image and so on.
If you can not use third-party libraries - check library's source code, its pretty simple.